# Difference between services and exporting functions in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm a little confused about when to use a service, versus when to export functions or classes.

Here's what I mean by exporting a class: See the top answer here [Angular 2: Functions to be used across all components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40765728/angular-2-functions-to-be-used-across-all-components)

```
export class Utils {
    public static log(msg:string){
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Which is imported here and used

```
import {Utils} from './utils'

class parent{
   foo(s: string){
     Utils.log(s);
   }
}

class child{
   constructor(){
      Utils.log("Hello");
   }
}
```

And here's what I mean by exporting functions in place of a service:

```
export printAll(toPrint:string): void{
}
```

as seen in this question

[Angular service vs export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604501/angular-service-vs-export)

What's the difference between these approaches in comparison to using a service? What's the difference between these two methods? Pros, cons? Thought process when deciding which to use?

Comment: there's a lot about this in the angular tutorial.  Services are part of the dependency injection framework at angular's core.  DI is useful for a number of reasons, but that's too broad a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- By using an exported function there is a chance to remove unused
  functions during the Building process and this can be taken into
  consideration as an advantage here.
- By using an services you are using a construction injection pattern
  which is one of the best practices for implementing `Inversion of Control (IOC)`.
- Generally speaking based on `service oriented architecture (SOA)`
  you use an services whenever an action or service will be used many
  times and in angular patters usually `callback to Back-end ( Rest-API, ... )` is usually implemented in services. because
  fetching data from back-end can be considered as an separate layer
  from the implementing app business in controller or component.